# Using the React Application for meta tags not reading in facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

using the react application and my application has to read meta tags differently with routing. using react-helmet for meta tags its appearing in elements but in view page source the meta tags are not appearing and every page should crawl in Facebook.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Helmet>

        <title>My Awesome Website</title>
        <meta name="title" content="My Awesome Website" />
        <meta name="description" content="This website is so awesome that I really don't think you can handle how much awesome that is happening here." />
        </Helmet>
        <p>Hello World</p>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: View Page Source option is the HTML source for it, basically the `index.html` page in your React app. The meta tags you have added here would only be added with JS

Comment: @Agney Thanks for the reply. Please help me out from this giving any reference

Comment: I can't think of a reference. But I guess this is the way things are. If you add things to `index.html` it shows up in View Page source. Anything you add on React components are basically JavaScript. They would show up only when rendered in the browser (unless you render it server side like NextJS or Gatsby)

Comment: As i have used server.js file for adding all pages metatags in index.html still the issue isn't resolved